# Deleted duplicates shouldn't reject a migration

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

Consider the following case:

1. A question is posted on Stack Overflow, that is clearly an MSO topic
2. It is closed as such, and migrated.
3. Unfortunately, the asker didn't do any research, so its actually a duplicate
4. It is correctly closed as a duplicate
5. It is deleted. (**actually** necessary)
6. This rejects the migration, throwing the off-topic post *back* on SO.

If a question is a duplicate, it still clearly belonged on the migration target site. Rejecting such migrations doesn't help anything.

Can we stop rejecting migrations for duplicate questions (I know this is a system thing, not a user thing)? It isn't helping anything, and now we have to go clean up the question on the source site.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this is contrary to the "don't migrate crap" guideline.

Comment: @Servy It could have been a good "sign-post" duplicate, in which case it wouldn't be violating that (granted, the post inspiring this request was not).

Comment: Only a small minority of duplicates are going to make good signposts, so I'm inclined to give preference to handling the typical case, in which the duplicate isn't going to be a useful signpost.

Comment: @Servy: But the post got answers (probably quality ones) on the target site (by following the dupe-notice), the migrated post is unlikely to be deleted as it is a duplicate, and anyway the original should just die as fast as possible. Thus, seeing duplicate-closing as accepting instead of rejecting is the best way to go all around.

Comment: Hmm.. Do we really want signposts from SO pointing to MSO? Am conflicted.

Comment: @Will Its worse than that. The rejected migration on SO *has no indication of the duplicate* of course, since its on SO, it should just be closed/deleted anyways

Comment: Now let's think about a post which was also answered (with upvotes) before it was migrated, dupe-closed, and sent back. Now it will stay around until it's manually cleaned up for sure.

Comment: Rejected migrations are [still on hold](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970201/how-to-get-50-reputations-so-i-can-write-a-comment) when the [duplicate on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287755/how-to-get-50-reputations-so-i-can-write-a-comment) has been deleted. What exactly is wrong with that?

Comment: @Deduplicator: got any examples of that? I'd think the post would still be on hold / closed.

Comment: If the migrated question gets closed as a duplicate *and* is bad enough that it deserves to be deleted as well, then why not have the system just go delete it on the source site too and not worry about all this rejection nonsense?

Comment: @animuson That sounds good

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This is fixed as of yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127434/dont-reverse-migrations-on-deleted-posts-if-they-were-merged-first/329130#329130) - deletion will no longer reject migration on questions if they were first closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Even small fixes make it seem like there is at least some work being done to keep the main QA system maintained. This one actually did annoy me from time to time as well.