# Prevent rejected migrations for duplicate closed questions that get deleted by a moderator

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, moderators, migrated-questions

Unless something has changed I always assumed that posts that got migrated from Main to Meta and then closed as a duplicate stayed on Meta and certainly didn't lead to a rejected migration.
I'm a firm believer that [rejected migrations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354350/i-also-hate-low-quality-non-researched-clueless-meta-questions-that-get-migr) are no joy, for anyone.

Today we had an usual "comment when down vote" post on Meta that was first posted on main: [Why downvote for no reason?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/383131/why-downvote-for-no-reason) and I did what I do in these cases: find a duplicate and hammer it closed.

There were some comment exchanges on the Q/A pair (an answer got migrated with it) that got flags so a moderator on duty came by, cleaned up and put the whole thing out of its misery by casting a binding delete vote.

To my surprise (and [that of the mod](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/46001270#46001270)) that caused a rejected migration event leading to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795310) being unlocked (but closed) on main again. This is not the kind of clean-up where the tools are helping us.

I'm not sure if this is a bug but I'm going to call it that anyway in the hope this gets solved within the 6 to 8 weeks timeframe. The [feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287761/deleted-duplicates-shouldnt-reject-a-migration) from 2015 didn't get enough attention. Stronger measures are needed.

Can you please prevent reject migrations for duplicated voted posts when those are deleted by a moderator?

Comment: Wait what a completely logical, timesaving feature request that was never actioned? SAY IT AIN'T SO!

Comment: How about we just don't allow Meta to reject migrations at all (i.e. you can close the question any time you want, but it can never leave)?

Comment: Hotel California style?

Comment: @Kevin then what happens when something is migrated to meta that should have stayed on the main site?

Comment: Tough luck? A re-post won't hurt.

Comment: @DanNeely: The moderators could always do a second migration manually. It should be pretty rare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is fixed as of yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127434/dont-reverse-migrations-on-deleted-posts-if-they-were-merged-first/329130#329130) - deletion will no longer reject migration on questions if they were first closed as a duplicate.